# Laravel: Add data to the $request->all()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I wan to add the sector id to the request but when I submit the data nothing store on it.
Here is my code

```
public function store(QuestionRequest $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        Question::create($data);
        $sectors =  Sector::lists('id');
        foreach($sectors as $sector){
            CustomizeQuestion::create(array_add($request->all(), 'sector_id', $sector));
        }

        flash()->success('New question has been added.');
        return redirect('questions');
    }
```

I have tried this code also but it is the same :

```
public function store(QuestionRequest $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        Question::create($data);
        $sectors =  Sector::lists('id');
        foreach($sectors as $sector){
            $data['sector_id'] = $sector;
            CustomizeQuestion::create($data);
        }

        flash()->success('New question has been added.');
        return redirect('questions');
    }
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Try doing dd($sector, array_add($request->all(), 'sector_id', $sector)); and paste the results

Comment: Would you add the Model CustomizeQuestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all check your `CustomizeQuestion` model. `sector_id` should be in `$fillable` array. Example:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'sector_id',
    'more',
    'and_more'
];
```

And if your form return only one `id` to `store` method no need  to use `foreach` or list your `id`. Simply do this:

```
$data['sector_id'] = $request['id'];
CustomizeQuestion::create($data);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you only want to add one 'id' to your request as you said, you can simply do this before creating anything :

```
$data = $request->all();
$data['sector_id'] = whatever you want;
Question::create($data);
```

Or like the second way you showed.

If this approach doesn't work verify if you have your properties specified in the model's fillable array and if you are using the correct property name as you specified in your migration.